# Keyword matching in an array/string of keywords using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a piece of PHP code as follows:

```
$words = array(
            'Artist' => '1',
            'Tony' => '2',
            'Scarface' => '3',
            'Omar' => '4',
            'Frank' => '5',
            'Torrentino' => '6',
            'Mel Gibson' => '7',
            'Frank Sinatra' => '8',
            'Shakes' => '9',
            'William Shakespeare' => '10'
    );
$text = "William Shakespeare is very famous in the world. An artist is a person engaged in one or more of any of a broad spectrum of activities related to creating art, practicing the arts, and/or demonstrating an art. Artist is a descriptive term applied to a person who engages in an activity deemed to be an art. Frank Sinatra was an American singer, actor, director, film producer, and conductor. Frank Sinatra was born on December 12, 1915, in Hoboken, New Jersey, the only child of Italian immigrants Natalina Garaventa and Antonino Martino Sinatra, and was raised Roman Catholic.";

$re = '/\b(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($keyword) {
    return preg_quote($keyword, '/');
}, array_keys($words))) . ')\b/i';

preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $keyword) {
    echo $keyword, " ", $words[$keyword], "\n";
}
```

The code returns the below:

`William Shakespeare 10 artist Artist 1 Frank 5 Frank 5`

The code works well to not echo the partial keywords such as `'Shakes' => '9'` in Shakespeare. However, as you can see the code can not detect `'Frank Sinatra' => '8'` as a keyword as it is in `Frank Sinatra was an American singer`, also `artist` does not have any value (i.e. `1`). Could you please help me to change the code somehow to echo `William Shakespeare 10 artist 1 Artist 1 Frank 5 Frank 5 Frank Sinatra 8 Frank Sinatra 8` instead of `William Shakespeare 10 artist Artist 1 Frank 5 Frank 5` in the current version. thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Output for your code is `William 9 World Cup 4 William Shakespeare 8` and not `World Cup 4 William Shakespeare 8` so it seems it works as you want

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, thank you Marcin, could you please review the question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to achieve result:

> William Shakespeare 10 artist 1 Artist 1 Frank Sinatra 8 Frank Sinatra
>   8

using the code:

```
<?php

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$words = array(
            'Artist' => '1',
            'Tony' => '2',
            'Scarface' => '3',
            'Omar' => '4',
            'Frank' => '5',
            'Torrentino' => '6',
            'Mel Gibson' => '7',
            'Frank Sinatra' => '8',
            'Shakes' => '9',
            'William Shakespeare' => '10'
    );


uksort($words, function ($a, $b) {
    $as = mb_strlen($a);
    $bs = mb_strlen($b);

    if ($as > $bs) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ($bs > $as) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;


});

$words_ci = array();

foreach ($words as $k => $v) {
    $words_ci[mb_strtolower($k)] = $v;
}

$text = "William Shakespeare is very famous in the world. An artist is a person engaged in one or more of any of a broad spectrum of activities related to creating art, practicing the arts, and/or demonstrating an art. Artist is a descriptive term applied to a person who engages in an activity deemed to be an art. Frank Sinatra was an American singer, actor, director, film producer, and conductor. Frank Sinatra was born on December 12, 1915, in Hoboken, New Jersey, the only child of Italian immigrants Natalina Garaventa and Antonino Martino Sinatra, and was raised Roman Catholic.";

$re = '/\b(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($keyword) {
    return preg_quote($keyword, '/');
}, array_keys($words))) . ')\b/i';



preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $keyword) {
    echo $keyword, " ", $words_ci[mb_strtolower($keyword)], "\n";
}
```